# Get a list of all the field values from a Foreign Key Table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

am new to Django and currently trying the Foreign Key concept. I have three models as shown below.

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    basket_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.basket_name

class Product(models.Model):
    Grams = 'GM'
    Kilograms = 'KG'
    WeightBased = 'WPG'
    QuantityBased = 'CPG'
    PRODUCT_UNIT_WT_CHOICES=[
        (Grams, 'Grams'),
        (Kilograms, 'Kilograms')
    ]
    PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES =[
        (WeightBased, 'Weight Based Product'),
        (QuantityBased, 'Quantity Based Product')
    ]
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    product_unit_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    product_unit_weight_units = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_UNIT_WT_CHOICES, default=Grams)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES, default=QuantityBased)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=imageUploadPath, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

class BasketProductMapping(models.Model):
    basket_reference = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_reference = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mapped_basket_name = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=False, blank=False)
    mapped_product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_price', 'product_unit_weight',
                    'product_unit_weight_units', 'product_type', 'product_image']

class BasketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    basket = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Basket
        fields = ('id', 'basket_name')

class BasketProductMappingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    basket_reference = serializers.CharField(source ='basket.basket_name', read_only=True)
    product_reference = serializers.CharField(source='product.product_name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BasketProductMapping
        fields = ['id', 'basket_reference', 'product_reference', 'mapped_basket_name', 'mapped_product_name']
```

What I am trying to achieve is get a list of all the values in 'basket_name' and 'product_name' when I call the **BasketProductMappingSerializer**. But the output I am getting is this:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Basket Product Mapping List",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "mapped_basket_name": "A1",
            "mapped_product_name": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my views.py code:

```
class BasketProductViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.GET.get('id'):
            print('Basket Product Mapping Details')
            basketProductMappingData = BasketProductMapping.get(id = request.GET.get('id'))
            serializer = BasketProductMappingSerializer(basketProductMappingData)
        else:
            basketProductMappingData = BasketProductMapping.objects.all().values('id', 'basket_reference__basket_name', 'product_reference__product_name', 'mapped_basket_name', 'mapped_product_name')
            serializer = BasketProductMappingSerializer(basketProductMappingData, many=True)
        response = {'status':1, 'message':"Basket Product Mapping List", 'data':serializer.data}
```

Where am I going wrong? Sorry if my question is very trivial. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: can you add your views code ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to include the views code.

Answer (score 0):

i see that there is an error in your views `BasketProductMapping.get(id = request.GET.get('id'))` should be `BasketProductMapping.objects.get(id = request.GET.get('id'))`

i don't know if it gonna work but can you try

```
basket_reference = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source ='basket.basket_name')
product_reference = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.product_name')
```

instead of

```
basket_reference = serializers.CharField(source ='basket.basket_name', read_only=True)
product_reference = serializers.CharField(source='product.product_name', read_only=True)
```